# How to choose first and last tick labels in an axis and define the number of major ticks between it?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm doing some templates and making some options to control the tick distribution in an axis. I've added few options so far and the last I couldn't manage to do by myself. I want to be able to choose:

1. The first and last major ticks in axis
2. Choose the number of major ticks between first and last ticks and automatically distribute it linearly.

I already managed to do the first task, however I don't know how to do the second one.

Obs: I know how to do it using major and minor ticks, however I want to be able to do it only with major ticks.

Here is a sample of the code:

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import FixedLocator

data = np.loadtxt('my_data.dat')        # Load Data File

x = data[:,0]
y = data[:,6]

x_first_tick = 0
x_last_tick = 2

y_first_tick = 0
y_last_tick = 100

x_major_ticks = 5                    # Number of major ticks in x axis
y_major_ticks = 5                    # Number of major ticks in y axis

x_locs= [x_first_tick, x_last_tick]
y_locs =[y_first_tick, y_last_tick]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()
ax.scatter(x, y, s=1)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(FixedLocator(locs = x_locs))
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(FixedLocator(locs = y_locs))

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Graph Output:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** Posting the template options I made using the principle posted by 
JohanC

```
    # Major Tick Options:
    # '1' : Choose number of major ticks,
    # '2' : Choose first, last and number of major ticks,
    # '3' : Linear Spacing from min to max with stepsize, 
    # '4' : Specify major ticks exactly,
    # None: default.

    if control_x_tick_type == '1':
        ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(x_majorT))

    elif control_y_tick_type == '2':
        ax.set_xticks([x_first_tick + (x_last_tick - x_first_tick) * i / (x_majorT - 1) for i in range(x_majorT)], minor=False)

    elif control_x_tick_type == '3':
        ax.set_xticks([1*i for i in np.arange(x_first_tick, x_last_tick, x_tick_step)])

    elif control_x_tick_type == '4':
        x_locs = (np.array(x_locs, dtype = float))
        ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(FixedLocator(locs = x_locs))

    else:
        pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ticks can be set as follows:

```
ax.set_xticks(
    [x_first_tick + (x_last_tick - x_first_tick) * i / (x_major_ticks - 1) for i in range(x_major_ticks)],
    minor=False)
ax.set_yticks(
    [y_first_tick + (y_last_tick - y_first_tick) * i / (y_major_ticks - 1) for i in range(y_major_ticks)],
    minor=False)
```

The parameter `minor` defaults to `False` and can be omitted. Use `minor=True` for the minor ticks.

Comment: Thank you! The same principle also worked for some of other options I implemented.